# Dynamically Access Variable Inside a Struct C++

Tags: c++, object, struct, dynamic

I'm new to C++ and very confused on how to approach this. In Javascript, I can do something like this to access an object dynamically very easily:

```
function someItem(prop) {
    const item = {
        prop1: 'hey',
        prop2: 'hello'
    };
    return item[prop];
}
```

In C++, I'm assuming I have to use a Struct, but after that I'm stuck on how to access the struct member variables dynamically.

```
void SomeItem(Property Prop)
{
    struct Item
    {
        Proper Prop1;
        Proper Prop2;
    };
    // Item[Prop] ??
 }
```

This could be terrible code but I'm very confused on how to approach this.

Comment: Objects in Javascript are more similar to `std::unordered_map<std::string, sta::any>` in C++, than actual C++ objets.

Comment: For your struct you declared a type. You don't have an instance so you can't access the non-static member variables.

Comment: It's somewhat difficult to suggest an alternative because I think we would want more context.

Comment: Side note: dynamic access of pretty much anything has a cost. C++ is all about keeping the costs as low as possible. To make sure you accept, or at least understand, that what you are doing has performance implications, you generally have to ask for it, and that often means writing it yourself.

Comment: my use case is very light, but nonetheless, this was very informative. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple example of how to create an instance of a `struct` and then access its members:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Item {
    std::string prop1 = "hey";
    std::string prop2 = "hello";
};

int main() {
    Item myItem;
    std::cout << myItem.prop1 << std::endl; // This prints "hey"
    std::cout << myItem.prop2 << std::endl; // This prints "hello"
    return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like you might want a map. A map has keys and values associated with them, as an example you could have a key `"prop1"` be associated with a value `"hey"`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
    myMap["prop1"] = "hey";
    myMap["prop2"] = "hello";
    std::cout << myMap["prop1"] << std::endl; // This print "hey"
    std::cout << myMap["prop2"] << std::endl; // This print "hello"
    return 0;
}
```

The first would be considered "normal" `struct` usage in C++ and the other is more applicable to cases where you have to look things up by keys

Comment: In the second example, note that using `[]` to read elements will cause the element to be inserted if it's missing. If you use `.at()`, you'll get an exception on a missing element instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, in C++ you would not define a custom structure for this, but rather use a `std::unordered_map`. I don't know Javascript, though if `Property` is an enum (it could be something else with small modifications) and `return item[prop];` is supposed to return a string, then this might be close:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

enum class Property { prop1,prop2};

std::string someItem(Property p){
    const std::unordered_map<Property,std::string> item{
        {Property::prop1,"hey"},
        {Property::prop2,"hello"}
    };
    auto it = item.find(p);
    if (it == item.end()) throw "unknown prop";
    return it->second;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << someItem(Property::prop1);
}
```

`std::unordered_map` does have a `operator[]` that you could use like so `return item[p];`, but it inserts an element into the map when none is found for the given key. This is not always desirable, and not possible when the map is `const`.